# ¿Como validar una contraseña usando Regex android?

Tags: android, android-studio, regex, login

Estoy actualmente desarrollando un `login` de usuario, quiero validar la contraseña de la siguiente manera:

- Al menos una letra mayúscula
- Al menos una letra minúscula
- Al menos 1 numero
- Al menos un caracter especial
- Que una letra, numero o caracter especial no se repita 3 veces seguidas
- Sin espacios entre los caracteres de la contraseña
- Mínimo 8 caracteres, máximo 16.

Investigando he conseguido que se hace con `Regex` usando la propiedad `matches`, el problema es que cuando estoy validando mi contraseña una vez supero los 8 caracteres, me pide una mayúscula, la coloco, y me sigue pidiendo una mayúscula, normalmente se queda siempre pidiendo mayúscula, algunas de las variaciones que he hecho, me ha solicitado una mayúscula, luego una minúscula y de nuevo mayúscula, queda en un bucle, y no entiendo por que no me valida la contraseña como deseo, acá mi código:

```
private void attemptLogin() {

        // Reset errors.
        email.setError(null);
        password.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
        String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
            email.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = email;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailInValid(Email)) {
            email.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = email;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Password)){
            password.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = password;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (!Password.matches("(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])")){
            password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_special_caracter));
            focusView = password;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (!Password.matches("(?=.*[0-9])")){
            password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_number));
            focusView = password;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (!Password.matches("(?=.*[a-z])")){
            password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_lowercase_caracter));
            focusView = password;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (!Password.matches("(?=.*[A-Z])")){
            password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_uppercase_caracter));
            focusView = password;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (!Password.matches(".{8,15}")){
            password.setError(getString(R.string.error_too_short_password));
            focusView = password;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (!Password.matches("(?=\\S+$)")){
            password.setError(getString(R.string.error_spaces));
            focusView = password;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContainerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

El ultimo método que es evitar que un caracter, numero o letra se repita 3 veces seguidas aun no consigo la forma de hacerlo con el `Regex` , espero puedan ayudarme y si conocen algún método para hacer esto de mejor manera, acepto sugerencias, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una alternativa a usar regex para las verificaciones.
Resuelve todos los items en una sola pasada por la clave.

El órden de los caracteres viene dado por la [Tabla ASCII](https://ascii.cl/), lo que permite evaluar a los mismos dentro de ciertos rangos.

Para hacerlo más gráfico use los caracteres pero se podria haber hecho comparando contra el código del caracter. (En lugar de `c > 'A'`, podria haber sido `c > 65` )

```
public boolean validarPwd(String pwd){
    boolean rtn = true;
    int seguidos = 0;
    char ultimo = 0xFF;

    int minuscula = 0;
    int mayuscula = 0;
    int numero = 0;
    int especial = 0;
    boolean espacio = false;
    if(pwd.length() < 8 || pwd.length() > 16) return false; // tamaño
    for(int i=0;i<pwd.length(); i++){
        char c = pwd.charAt(i);
        if(c <= ' ' || c > '~' ){
            rtn = false; //Espacio o fuera de rango
            break;
        } 
        if( (c > ' ' && c < '0') || (c >= ':' && c < 'A') || (c >= '[' && c < 'a') || (c >= '{' && c < 127) ){
            especial++;
        }
        if(c >= '0' && c < ':') numero++;
        if(c >= 'A' && c < '[') mayuscula++;
        if(c >= 'a' && c < '{') minuscula++;

        seguidos = (c==ultimo) ? seguidos + 1 : 0;
        if(seguidos >= 2){ 
                rtn = false; // 3 seguidos
                break;
        }
        ultimo = c;
    }
    rtn = rtn && especial > 0 && numero > 0 && minuscula > 0 && mayuscula > 0;
    return rtn;
 }
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, otra forma de hacer estas validaciones :)

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, era un error de sintaxis del `Regex`, dejo la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien.

```
 private void attemptLogin() {

            // Reset errors.
            email.setError(null);
            password.setError(null);

            // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
            String Email = email.getText().toString().trim();
            String Password = password.getText().toString().trim();

            boolean cancel = false;
            View focusView = null;

            // Check for a valid email address.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Email)) {
                email.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                focusView = email;
                cancel = true;
            } else if (!isEmailInValid(Email)) {
                email.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
                focusView = email;
                cancel = true;
            }

            // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Password)){
                password.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
                focusView = password;
                cancel = true;
            }

            if (!Password.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*+=?-].*")){
                password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_special_caracter));
                focusView = password;
                cancel = true;
            }

            if (!Password.matches(".*\\d.*")){
                password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_number));
                focusView = password;
                cancel = true;
            }

            if (!Password.matches(".*[a-z].*")){
                password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_lowercase_caracter));
                focusView = password;
                cancel = true;
            }

            if (!Password.matches(".*[A-Z].*")){
                password.setError(getString(R.string.error_not_find_uppercase_caracter));
                focusView = password;
                cancel = true;
            }

            if (!Password.matches(".{8,15}")){
                password.setError(getString(R.string.error_too_short_password));
                focusView = password;
                cancel = true;
            }

            if (Password.matches(".*\\s.*")){
                password.setError(getString(R.string.error_spaces));
                focusView = password;
                cancel = true;
            }

            if (cancel) {
                // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
                // form field with an error.
                focusView.requestFocus();
            } else {
                // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
                // perform the user login attempt.
                showProgress(true);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContainerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
```